# Go To Previous Page and Refresh - both in one button using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way to create a button which will on click take you to previous page 
and then refresh the page immediately? I use the following code to go back to previous page but it does not reload/refresh..

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="javascript: history.go(-1)">
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Does it have to work just like the back button? I.e. resubmit a form if a form was send?

Comment: POST resending has a solution. it's called `header` in PHP. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-303-redirect/ this prevents POST resubmission while moving backwards in history.

Comment: Hi,PeeHaa  Thanks for your reply. .. No.. Not just like back button but also after refresh the page when it takes the user to the previous page. However I have got my solution. I just used this- onClick="location.href = document.referrer; and it is working.

Comment: I am also using "location.href = document.referrer" but it creates a new entry in the history which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to refresh the loaded page would be to use `window.location.reload()` in the new page.

You could try getting the last URL using `document.referrer` (or by keeping a history of their page views in a cookie) and then adding something to the hash to make it like:

http://stackoverflow.com#didGoBack

Then, in javascript, check to see if that hash exists using `window.location.hash` and if so, reload the page. Note. the referrer won't be set unless they arrived at that page via a link.

Comment: Hi, Jesse Bunch.. Thanks for your reply. I tried this - onClick="location.href = document.referrer; and it is working exactly the way I wanted. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think I invented a way of doing this. By adding a random parameter to url, we force browser to refresh...

```
var backLocation = document.referrer;
if (backLocation) {
    if (backLocation.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        backLocation += "&randomParam=" + new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        backLocation += "?randomParam=" + new Date().getTime();
    }
    window.location.assign(backLocation);
}
```